# How to check if a Gtk.ListStore is empty in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, is-empty

I want to check with an if statement if my Gtk.ListStore is empty. This means, there are no rows on it. I am using Gtk+3 and Python 3.5.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Gtk.ListStore`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/ListStore.html#Gtk.ListStore) implements the interface [`Gtk.TreeModel`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeModel.html#Gtk.TreeModel). You can use [`get_iter_first`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeModel.html#Gtk.TreeModel.get_iter_first) to check if the store it's empty.

With python, you can also use the `len()` method to check the size of the store, if 0 (zero), then it's empty. eg:

```
if (len(store)==0):
   #Empty
   ...
else:
   #NotEmpty
   ...
```

The size of the store equals the number of rows:

```
nrows=len(store)
```